# how to use ~\ref

Tags: cross-referencing

I tried to connect lemmas and the number followed by it using `~\ref{lemma1}` but some times the number goes to the next line even though I use tilde sign `~`. What is your suggestion?

Here is one line of text:

```
by Lemma ~\ref{th6} and Lemma ~\ref{th8}.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You shouldn't leave a space before `~`: `by Lemma~\ref{th6}`

Comment: @egreg Isn't that the answer?

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly it was the problem and I easily fix it. ;)

Answer (score 6):

The working of `~` relies on the fact that there are no other spaces around. So the correct input is

```
by Lemma~\ref{th6}
```

If you type `Lemma ~\ref{th6}` you get *two* spaces and the first one can be used for breaking the line.